# How do I get the first n records, per foreign key with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have the following table:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | table2_id | type |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 |       100 | A    |
|  2 |       100 | B    |
|  3 |       100 | C    |
|  4 |       100 | A    |
|  5 |       250 | A    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

I need a select statement that would get all the records before the first occurrence of type C, per table2_id.
So I want records 1, 2, and 5

I'd do this in code with a loop, but I need to do it in MySQL specifically.

Comment: what does "before" mean? sql data doesn't have any intrinsic order, you have to specify exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        min(case when type = 'C' then id end) over(partition by table2_id) min_id
    from mytable t
) t
where min_id is null or id < min_id
```

In all versions, you could use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.table2_id = t.table2_id and t1.id <= t.id and t1.type = 'C'
)
```